# How to get a CSR for Github Pages website

Tags: github, github-pages, csr, namecheap

I have currently connected GitHub pages with a domain name from namecheap.com. I recently bought an SSL certificate from NameCheap as well.

How do I get a CSR from GitHub to configure the SSL certificate?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 4):

If you go to your Github Repo which holds the hosted page, click Settings, then go to Pages and there's a box you can check titled "Enforce HTTPS". Check that and it should be enabled instantly.

[image]

No need to buy an SSL cert from NameCheap.